# string token in a string token

Tags: c, string, token, strtok

Hi im trying to use strtok to seperate a file read.
the text file just has a list of names read into one char array at first stored in to data.
ive removed the file reading bit and shown the array for simplicity.

```
int main()
{
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    
    char data[128] = "john smith\nbob jones\nrobert brown";

    char *argv [50];

    char * token = strtok(data, "\n"); // separates data into lines  
  
    while( token != NULL ) 
    {
        insertAtBeginning(&head, token); //LL the data gets stored in 
        token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }          
   }
```

I have managed to split the data into lines, however i want to split the one line - token into an array by the " ".
so i want argv[0] = "john" and argv[1] = smith.
this argv array then gets stored into the linked list instead of "token" at the line.
thanks any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Just use as the separator in calls of strtok the string " \t\n".

Comment: Also, you can probably do this without the intermediate argv array, but we'd need to know more about `struct Node` to say for sure, especially whether the data is replicated into the node, or it is just hosting pointers to the data itself from the original buffer.

Comment: You can nest tokenizations when you use the re-entrant `strtok_r` with two different reference states, so you could toenize on newlines first, then tokenize the lines on space.

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't just do `size_t n = strlen(data);
for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  if(isspace(data[i]))
    data[i] = '\0';
}`